# DBEdit allow to delete value while DataSource.AutoEdit is false

Tags: delphi, datasource

Good day!

I have a Query, DataSource and DBEdit. DataSource.AutoEdit is false. Query.State is not in dsEdit or dsInsert. So I can't change the value in DBEdit. But if I press Delete key, value in DBEdit deletes (Query.State doesn't change). And if focus leaves this DBEdit, I receive an "Dataset not in edit or insert mode". Is that a some bug or something else and how can I fix this? I've tested this in new simple projects to be sure that the problem is not in my project.

Delphi version: Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171

Comment: *how can I fix this?* Hmm, Carroll answered this few years ago: “Where should I go?" - Alice. "That depends on where you want to end up." - The Cheshire Cat. // ESR answered as well: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal // no one but you knows how your programs should behave, you may tell it or conceal this...

Comment: "That depends on where you want to end up."

I want that TDBEdit works correctly. If a set AutoEdit to false, DBEdit must be readonly (for all key includind Delete).

Comment: In a simple project with nothing more than one DBGrid, one DBNavigator, one DBEdit, one DataSource, one ADODataSet, one field, it behaves correctly for me. The Delete key is suppressed when not in edit state. Also Delphi XE. When does it not work?

Comment: hvd, I've created new project with one DBEdit, one ADOQuery and one DataSource. Then set AutoEdit to false and the Delete Key is not suppressed when query is not in edit state. I understand that this is unusual situation, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: @GaaraofDesert My Delphi version is the same as yours, and it works for me, so I think the code to suppress it must be there, but the code to suppress it is wrong in that it won't work on all systems (and won't on yours)?

Comment: @hvd, Maybe. I've tested this on Windows XP, Windows 7 and everywhere the bug takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set [TDBEdit.ReadOnly](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBEdit.ReadOnly) to true, when the dataset is not in edit state and change it as the dataset [state changes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSource.OnStateChange).

---

Google shows the [bug report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88917) in 1st 5 links

Comment: I do think it's a bug, or an unnecessary inconsistency at the least. `AutoEdit = False` means you can't edit the fields unless you manually change the dataset's state, and this is reflected by the DBEdit being read-only in pretty much all cases *other* than the Delete key. So why is the Delete key different?

Comment: No, I am managing Edit State manually. If I set AutoEdit to false, I want that all DBedits on my form will be readonly. And they are readonly (I can't change any value, can't paste or cut or enter new value). But the key "Delete" deletes the symbols. it seems that AutoEdit doesn't influence on VK_DELETE.

Comment: @hvd what are those cases ? i bet they are when field or dataset are explicitly set to readonly. That was not the case here. It may be bad design arguably, yet not direct bug.

Comment: @Arioch'The Regular editing. Type a character in a DBEdit linked to a datasource that's not in edit state with AutoEdit = False and nothing will happen.

Comment: @GaaraofDesert well, if other edits supresses, then that might have sense. What can say google allmighty ?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=%22TDBEdit%22+delete+key+site:qc.embarcadero.com&sourceid=opera     http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88917

Comment: Then obviously one can 1) subclass(make an ancestor) over TDbEdit / 2) subclass DataSource to tweak db-edits 3) patch TDbEdit VMT to change reaction to VK_DELETE

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly my situation - http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88917

Will try to fix it manually.

Comment: frankly it is so amazingly easy to find that i wonder why Google failed you

Comment: Arioch 'The, sorry, i tried to find solution on several forums for programmers and forgot to check bug-reports.